# How to change .aab of current closed test without beginning new test

Tags: android, google-play-console

my closed test phase of 14 days is finally over. It was difficult to find 20 people to test the app. But now I got a message that a sdk which is included in the firebase auth sdk is insecure. I updated the sdk now. But how can I use the new aab to ask for production access.

I hope that I dont have to do another 14 days of testing. I dont think I can get the 20 users to install it again for 14 days. Any help ? Or do you think I schould just ask for production access?